# Warning C4091 in template function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I have the code that was compiled in VS-2010 without a warning:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    class InternalClass;
};

class MyClass::InternalClass {
};

template<class QWERTY>
void Func( QWERTY& arg )
{
    typename QWERTY::InternalClass;
}

int main()
{
    MyClass var;
    Func( var );
    return 0;
}
```

Now I compile this code in VS-2017 and get the warning 4091:

```
warning C4091: '': ignored on left of 'MyClass::InternalClass' when no variable is declared
```

What should I do if I want to keep type checking (and do not want a warning :))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is complaining that this line

```
typename QWERTY::InternalClass;
```

is doing nothing since you aren't declaring a variable or doing anything meaningful to it.  And it's essentially the same as having a line of

```
int;
```

To get rid of the warning, an easy workaround would be to actually use it. e.g.

```
using MyType = typename QWERTY::InternalClass;
//or
typename QWERTY::InternalClass myObj;
//myObj....
```

Doing so will keep type checkings as well.

Comment: Well, "using" is the closest approach. Thank you!

Comment: `using MyType = typename QWERTY::InternalClass;` without using `MyType` might produce warnings.

Comment: `typename QWERTY::InternalClass myObj;` add the requirement of default constructible (and create the object which might be heavy to construct).

Comment: `using MyType = typename QWERTY::InternalClass;` actually creates no warnings under `Wall` in VS -- Not sure about other compilers. I assume it's OK to define a type without actually using it.

Comment: @Jarod42 That's just an example of a possible way to get rid of the warning - given the warning says no variable is declared.

Comment: Clang has warning for unused local types.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks for pointing that out. Agree! A good code should not have any unused types.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way

```
template <class QWERTY,
          typename SFINAE = typename QWERTY::InternalClass>
void Func( QWERTY& arg )
{
}
```

Pitfall is that `Func<int, void>(i)` would be correct.

A more correct (and more verbose) way would be:

```
template <class QWERTY,
          std::enable_if_t<hasInternalClass<QWERTY>::value, void*> = nullptr>
void Func(QWERTY& arg)
{
}
```

with appropriate traits.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Actually the project I digging is quite big so I prefer to minimize changes :)